# How can I get the password of an openID associated site?

Tags: login, authentication, openid, stack-overflow

Login to Stackoverflow.com supports OpenID authentication.  Alternatively, we can login using using Google account (among others).

Once we associate any supported account, an openID is associated with SO.

How to get password of this associated openID?  Currently I use google credential to access SO, but want to use open id credential (explicitly).

Comment: the whole point of openID is that authentication is delegated to the site handling the auth. The password is the same that you use to login to that site. Having said that, I'm not clear what your question is - do you want to switch to StackID? Do you want to get openID password? Your title one, your question body is something else

Comment: More specifically, _there is no password_ for the account. You have to log in with the Google account.

Comment: @Sathya, and nhinkle, Thanks for the response. On exploring further i got to know that openid url is not account specific, but account provider specific. Entering openid url navigates to account provider specific page where credentials are validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an explicit "OpenID credential". OpenID is a standard for authentication; the whole point of it is that you have an account from some provider, and they authenticate you for other sites. It's not that a Google account comes with some OpenID certificate; the Google account *is* the OpenID account.

Comment: @What should I do, if i have to create authentication mechanism, that is also open id. For example, with credentials that are stored In the database, uses should be able to login to sites where open id is supported

Comment: @Tilak that constitutes another question altogether. You comment reminds me of the [classic XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please be specific in what you want to ask and where you want to ask, for now, I'm migrating this to webapps